# How to add a new line into existing JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I defined a `body` JSON, like this:

```
$body = [
        "line1" => "test1",
        "line2" => "test2",
    ];
```

And, if a condition is true, I need to add a third line, si I'm doing this:

```
$body = [
        "line3" => "test3",
     ];
```

But what I'm doing is overwriting the `$body`, because when I return this, I'm getting:

```
{
"line3": "test3"
}
```

So, how can I add a third line to an existing JSON instead of overwriting it?

Comment: Actually, you have a defined body Array not the JSON

Comment: Convert your json to php array first, insert your new element and convert back to json

Comment: This is actually nothing to do with JSON directly, it's about how you add things to an array in php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the subscript operator (`[]`) to add elements to an array:

```php
$body["line3"] = "test3";
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're generating a `JSON` but, before you return it like a `JsonResponse`, you're working with an array, so technically, your `$body` is an array. You can add a new line to your `$body` just like the same way you would add a new item to an array.